# Add secondary sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following template: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/aldemair-productions/project.html

When I scroll up I would like the secondary nav to become fixed just under the header.

and I have my js to add and remove the fix class for the secondary nav in red:

```
if($(".project-page").length) {
    //var fixedNav = new Foundation.Sticky($('.sticky'));

    $(".inner-inner-wrap").on('scroll', function() {
        wrapper = $('.main-wrapper');
        offset = wrapper.offset();
        wrapperViewportOffsetTop = offset.top - $(document).scrollTop();
        console.log(wrapperViewportOffsetTop);

        if(wrapperViewportOffsetTop <= 150) {
            //$('.main-wrapper').addClass('fixed-wrapper');
            $('.project-nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
        }
        else {
            //$('.main-wrapper').removeClass('fixed-wrapper');
            $('.project-nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
        }
    });
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();

    // $('.project-nav').css('margin-top', viewPortHeight);
    // $('.main-wrapper').css('margin-top', '-90px');
}
```

The result is not very good. I expect the secondary nav to get fixed below the header once the condition in the JS has been met.

Where/how can I improve this?

Comment: first tthings first, your main wrapper is on top of your header (due to higher z-index) which doesn't make sense if you want the seondary nav to be under the header. Also in firefox the page won't scroll when hovering the video.

Comment: @Alex if my answer is useful, please mark it as best answer to finishing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = $("body").scrollTop();
    var headerHeight = $("header").height();
    var navHeight = $("nav").height();

    if (scrollTop <= headerHeight)
        $("nav").css("top", headerHeight - scrollTop);  
    else
        $("nav").css("top", "0px");  
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #03A9F4;
}

nav {
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 8px;
    right: 8px;
    background: #FFC107;    
}

div {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<div></div>
```